# Php form - Add redirect as well as a opt in box

Tags: php, html

I am new to this and trying to figure out how to add a few extra features to this code.

1. On submit the page needs to redirect to an external URL i.e. www.google.com
2. The checkbox must be automatically checked and when the client gets emailed the details it must return TRUE/FALSE for subscriptions to the newsletter (so client knows whether they want to opt in or not)

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    // Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
    $emailTo = 'nissberry@gmail.com';

    $subscriber_email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    if (!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array('valid' => 0, 'message' => 'Insert a valid email address!');
        echo json_encode($array);
    } else {
        $array = array('valid' => 1, 'message' => 'Thanks for your subscription!');
        echo json_encode($array);

        // Send email
        $subject = 'New Subscriber (Free eBook)!';
        $body = "You have a new subscriber!\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
        // uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
        // $headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $subscriber_email;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body);
    }
?>
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="assets/subscribe.php" method="post">                                              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="subscribe-email form-control" id="subscribe-email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Receive your free eBook</button>
    <br>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checked"> Receive Our Monthly Newsletter
        </label>
    </div>                                             
</form>
<div class="success-message"></div>
<div class="error-message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If there was no output before mail() function (no echo or html) you
   could use this just before closing PHP tag:

   ```
   header("Location: www.google.com");
   exit;
   ```

   So to redirect with PHP you need to remove all echo's from your code. If this can't be done, use javascript:

   ```
   window.location.replace("www.google.com");
   ```
2. Add 'checked' attribute to your checkbox. It should have a name too,
   so you can access it with global $_POST variable:

   ```
   <input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" class="checked" checked>
   ```

   Then you can extend your message:

   ```
   $newsletter_subscription = isset($_POST['newsletter']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
   $body .= 'Newsletter subscription: '.$newsletter_subscription;
   ```

Comment: Adding those two lines just before the closing tag, results in a redirect even if someone enters an invalid email address.. You must add it after `mail()` inside the else condition.

Comment: @Boratzan The question is 'On submit the page needs to redirect', not 'On subscription success the page needs to redirect', so that is what I'm answering.

Comment: Well you got a point about him not asking right, but his code does show you that he checks if it's an valid email addres.. Why would he check and echo an result if the user gets redirected anyway? Makes no sense.

Comment: I have removed the echo() from both the if & else and added the header() just before the closing PHP tag - I get the email but the page doesn't redirect. Am I forgetting to take stuff out that prevents it from redirecting?

Comment: Thanks a mil for everyone's help!

Comment: @Nis, do you have any errors? header() function can be tricky, it will fail because of any output, including space or empty line. Does file 'assets/subscribe.php' contain only code you posted? Or maybe that code is in another file that you include on subscribe.php? When you open page source on your browser, is anything there?

Comment: You could also try removing space between "Location:" and site address, some browsers had problem with that

Comment: display the error using this     print_r(error_get_last());